# Using larger than or equal (>=) to in PreparedStatement in Java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, mariadb

I have a SQL statement that looks like this `SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA >= CHF ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT 10`. The statement works fine and now I'm trying to use it in Java with `PreparedStatement` with the following code (I left out the connection and the try blocks)

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA ? ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?";

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
statement.setString(1, searchDirection);
statement.setString(2, currencyCode);
statement.setInt(3, numberOfCurrenciesReturned);
```

I get the following output in the console when I print `statement`:

`sql : 'SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA ? ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?', parameters : ['>=','CHF',5]`

It all looks fine but it returns nothing. If I hard code `>=` in `sqlQuery` then it works fine but I rather not do that since I need to change it for different conditions to `<=`.

Is there any way around this or do I need to hard code it? I'm using Java 8, DBCP2 and MariaDB.

Comment: `PreparedStatement` parameters are deliberately escaped as-to not have any meaning in SQL other than a string type, ie. it won't treat it like an actual operator. Use 2 different `PreparedStatement`s, each with their own version of your SQL query. There's not enough "overhead" to even worry about this.

Comment: You could try `&lt;=` and `&gt;=`

Comment: If you do both `<=` and `>=` you're going to have overlap on your queries as well, for when the value is `==`

Comment: @j.seashell -  `&lt;=` is useful only to humans and only in web pages.  MySQL sees it as 5 characters.

Comment: @Rogue - `==` is not valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: @RickJames nor was it meant to be... the point is that they'll be overlapping if you do a less than or equals and a greater than or equals. I assumed the average reader would understand `==` to generally mean "equivalent".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's talk about why this is happening

There's a difference between the query itself and its parameters. `>=` is part of the query, `5` is a parameter.

Why is that? Well the prepared statement is trying to protect you against anything dangerous that might be passed in the query as a parameter. Say someone passes you something like `IS NULL; DROP TABLE VAL_DATA ...` instead of the string `>=`. You'll end up running `SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA IS NULL; DROP TABLE VAL_DATA;`. This will kill the entire `VAL_DATA` table. To avoid such security risks (and honest mistakes), prepared statements escape the values of parameters, and tricking them into doing so by generating the query string dynamically is probably not the best idea, although that'll work and that's what most other answers suggest you do.

I think that the best and most secure solution is to have a few different queries for the different cases. There aren't that many cases.

```
String queryLE = "SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA <= ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?";
String queryEQ = "SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA == ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?";
```

etc..

This is simple, secure, and safe. There's no way to nuke the entire database just by passing a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Operators can't be parameterized. I suggest using two different sqlQuery strings, one for less than, one for greater than, and switching between them based on the conditions you need to meet.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 different `PreparedStatement`'s.

`PreparedStatement` automatically escapes parameter input, so nothing you put there will be treated as an actual greater-than-or-equal comparison. This is desirable behavior, and having multiple `PreparedStatement`'s is not enough overhead to worry about (most programs have a great many statements).

Try something like:

```
private static final String sqlSelectGreaterOrEqual = "SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA >= ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?";
private static final String sqlSelectLessOrEqual = "SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA <= ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?";
private PreparedStatement psSelectGreaterOrEqual = null;
private PreparedStatement psSelectLessOrEqual = null;

// ... later in your program, or in your constructor, or some method

psSelectGreaterOrEqual = connection.prepareStatement(sqlSelectGreaterOrEqual);
psSelectLessOrEqual = connection.prepareStatement(sqlSelectLessOrEqual);

// ... later in your program in some method
public List<String> selectGreaterOrEqual(String criteria) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (psSelectGreaterOrEqual != null) {
        try {
            psSelectGreaterOrEqual.setString(1, criteria);
            rs = psSelectGreaterOrEqual.executeQuery();
            if (rs != null && rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
                while(rs.next()) {
                    results.add(rs.getString(1));
                    // etc... 
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Now, later in your program, just use whichever one makes sense, ie. maybe a different method call invokes one or the other, or an if statement decides which to use based on some other program logic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
String signString  = "<=" ;
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA ? "+ signString +" ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?";
```

Change signString as you need

Comment: This either completely voids the use of `PreparedStatement` (which everyone should be using), or makes the code harder to read/understand simply to avoid having 1 extra String in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try tokenizing your query, and then replacing the token with your `searchDirection` string.

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA %SEARCHDIRECTION% ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?";

sqlQuery = sqlQuery.replaceAll("%SEARCHDIRECTION%", searchDirection);

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
statement.setString(1, currencyCode);
statement.setInt(2, numberOfCurrenciesReturned);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [vijay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7392562/vijayksingh-vj) said: Operators can't be parameterized

So use this:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM VAL WHERE VAL_VALUTA " + searchDirection + " ? ORDER BY VAL_VALUTA ASC LIMIT ?";

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
statement.setString(1, currencyCode);
statement.setInt(2, numberOfCurrenciesReturned);
```